# C++ Macro Expander

Tags: c++, macros

Sometimes I run across quite complicated macros and I would like to view what they will expand to given the parameters (there are string concatenations in there as well). Is there by any chance a program out there that will expand the macros?

I am aware of the compiler flag `-E` but what about a single file (or preferably a single macro?)

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse will expand macros if you mouse over them.  For macros which include other macros, Eclipse can even step through the macro expansions one step at a time.

(You can use Eclipse for this even if you normally use another IDE.)

Answer (score 3):

The C and C++ preprocessor is called cpp on most systems - you can use it directly:

```
cpp somefile.c
```

will preprocess somefile.c, expanding macros and write the results to standard output. If you are using the Microsoft compiler:

```
cl -E somefile.c
```

will do the same, assuming you have the compiler on your PATH.

Comment: Sure - it effectively does what gcc -E does, though and if that doesn't fufill your needs neither will cpp.

Comment: Ok, I think I am not fully understanding the solution here. If I type `cpp myfile.h` in command prompt, it says `cpp is not a recognized command`.

Comment: Which platform are you on? Do you have a C++ compiler installed? If so, which one?

Comment: I am on Windows, and I have Visual Studio 2008 installed so it should be the MSVC compiler.

Answer (score 3):

A few options are:
***In GCC:***

gcc -E filename.c

***Using computers precompiler:***

```
cpp filename.c
```

***In visual Studio:***
Right-click on the file on the Solution Explorer, goto Properties. Under Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor & "Generate Preprocessed File"

Comment: problem with the approach with Visual Studio is that it applies to the whole project, which slows things down quite a bit

Comment: @Samaursa: The second option is best suited for you then. Yes you can run it from the command line. I believe it is by default already in your PATH so You can run it from cmd line.

Comment: Strangely enough it is not working for me. But I think there is something wrong with my setup as I recently installed TortoiseHg and when I typed in `hg` in the command prompt, it gave me an error saying command is not recognized

Comment: @Samaursa: Just find the exe's on your system and add their path under "Environment variables" "path". Right click My Computer->Advanced-> Environment Variables->System Variables->Path

Comment: If you mean find `cpp.exe`, no such file exists on my computer.

Comment: just wanted to add: `clang -E filename.c` is in LLVM (same as for gcc)

Answer (score 1):

[Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/macro-features.html) allows you to view what a macro expands to by holding Ctrl+Alt and hovering/clicking a macro.